# SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to $IP

Tags: java, сокет

Пытался на днях написать простой чат на Java с использованием соккетов.
Написал, попробовал, через 127.0.0.1, тут все работает.
Попробовал запустить клиент на другом компе (который подключен к интернету через тот же wifi, что и комп, на котором сервер) через внешний IP - выдает

```
SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to $IP
```

Проверил окрыт ли порт через сайт, — говорит что закрыт.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

---

### Sever.java

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket ss;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port){        
        this.port = port;       
        start();
    }

    public void run(){

        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server is running...");
            Socket socket;
            new client.StartWindow();

            while(true){
                socket = ss.accept();   
                ClientThread client = new ClientThread(socket);
                Config.users.add(client);
                client.start();
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Server was stopped.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Config.port == 45000
        Server server = new Server(Config.port);

    }
}
```

Comment: Пропинговал, - все нормально.

Comment: Добавьте после Вашего `System.out.println("Server is running...")` еще и `System.out.println("Address: " + ss.getInetAddress().getHostAddress())` - и посмотрите, на каком IP адресе он слушает.

Comment: И еще один момент: на компьютере, где Вы это запускаете, точно нет какой-нибудь firewall, которая блокирует входящие запросы?

Comment: Хмм..
Выдает адресс 0.0.0.0

Comment: Это при отключеном антивируснике и брандмауэре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хмм.. Выдает адресс 0.0.0.0

Это нормально, это значит сервер слушает все доступные сетевые интерфейсы.

`SocketTimeoutException` говорит о том, что сервер не ответил по той или иной причине.

Что проверить:

1. Проверьте что сервер запущен.
2. Проверьте, что на компьютере к которому вы подключаетесь открыт требуемый порт. В Windows Vista-7-8 обычно все закрыто встроенным в систему фаерволлом.
3. Если вы подключаетесь к серверу не напрямую (по локальной сети), а "через интернет", у него должен быть "белый" IP адрес, доступный снаружи.
4. Если вы подключаетесь к серверу, который присоединен к Сети через wifi роутер - обычно "белый" IP будет у роутера, а сам сервер скрыт за NAT-ом. На роутере нужно настроить проброс нужных портов на IP-адрес сервера в локальной сети.